# Spring Boot 2 - Where is FacebookAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to build facebook application with spring boot 2 and spring social. As I understand Spring Boot v2 pushed away bunch of things.

Where can I find FacebookAutoConfiguration class? Do I have to create it by myself now?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("facebook.clientId"),
            env.getProperty("facebook.clientSecret")));
    }

    ...
}
```

Look at [*this*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) to get details.

Comment: This is what I've done, but example you mentioned uses spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE. I want to use spring boot 2, that apparently doesn't have those configurers

Comment: That doesn't work. This configuration is not enough. First of all org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurer has 3 methods. Next, when I run the code it gives me NPE: